# как прямо в python коде скомпилировать другой python код в exe

Tags: python, компиляция, exe

Всем здравствуйте, я делаю программу которая будет создавать exe файлы. Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека которая позволяет прямо в python коде сделать из py exe без использования командной строки и всего остального?

Comment: `import os; os.system('pyinstaller --onefile main.py');` ?

Comment: А для этого на компьютере нужно иметь установленный python и какие нибудь библиотеки?

Comment: да, `python`, `pyinstaller`, все используемые в *компилируемом* проекте библиотеки

Comment: любые компоновщики требуют установленного `python` и всех библиотек, используемых в проекте. (я не слышал про те, которые не требуют)